# ListView: Retrieve Row Value on MouseEnter

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, mouseevent

I would like to retrieve the value of a row cell in a `ListView` a on a `MouseEnter` event. The `ListView` items are generated with `Binding`.

How can this be done without checking the `SelectedItem`?

**Update**

xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" MouseEnter="listView_MouseEnter">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Items"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StatusBarItem>The value is:</StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem x:Name="retrievedText" />
    </StatusBar>
</StackPanel>
```

cs

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int[] itemSource = { 1, 12, 3, 44, 12, 45, 6, 8, 9 };

        listView.ItemsSource = itemSource;
    }


    private void listView_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string hoveredItem = null; //This will be the retrieved value

        retrievedText.Content = hoveredItem;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can override the ItemContainerStyle to give the items a chance to handle the event:

xaml:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem} }">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseEnter" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

cs:

```
private void ListBoxItem_MouseEnter(object s, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.OriginalSource as ListBoxItem;

    // depends on what we have put in the content. e.g. string.
    var content = item.Content as string; 
}
```

In your case:

xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseEnter" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Items"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StatusBarItem>The value is:</StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem x:Name="retrievedText" />
    </StatusBar>
</StackPanel>
```

cs:

```
private void ListBoxItem_MouseEnter(object s, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.OriginalSource as ListBoxItem;
    retrievedText.Content = item.Content;
}
```

Comment: Change the type in `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}` if you have a customized style for the listboxitem. And you can easily apply the above ListBox code to ListView by just changing ListBox to ListView

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried adding your code but it did not work. I have updated my answer with code. My goal is to retrieve the value on mouse hover and add it to the status bar item.

Comment: This solution does not work with items that have `Data Binding`. My example code did not have any binding. I'd appreciate it if you could answer the same question related to `Binding`. Found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450402/retrieve-cell-value-on-mouseenter-in-a-multiple-column-listview-with-data-bindin