# Retrieve Cell Value On MouseEnter In A Multiple Column ListView With Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, mouseevent

I would like to retrieve the value from a Car Name column from a row in a `ListView` on a MouseEnter event and have the result display in a `TextBlock`.

How can I achieve this?

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="carList" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseEnter="carList_MouseEnter">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Car" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Make}" Header="Make" Width="Auto"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" Header="Year" Width="Auto"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox" Height="23" Margin="5,0,0,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

cs

```
    public Car SelectedCar { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

        int i = 0;
        string[] name = { "Sentra", "IS", "Camry", "s2000" };
        string[] make = { "Nissan", "Lexus", "Toyota", "Honda" };
        string[] year = { "2000", "2011", "2013", "2004" };

        foreach (string s in name)
        {
            cars.Add(new Car() { Name = name[i], Make = make[i], Year = year[i] });
            i++;
        }

        carList.ItemsSource = cars;

    }

    public class Car
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }

    }

    private void carList_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var carName = ""; //Name of car to display on hover
        textbox.Text = carName; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="carList" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseEnter="carList_MouseEnter">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseEnter" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Car" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Make}" Header="Make" Width="Auto"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" Header="Year" Width="Auto"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox" Height="23" Margin="5,0,0,5" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

cs:

```
private void ListBoxItem_MouseEnter(object s, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.OriginalSource as ListBoxItem;
    var car = item.Content as Car;
    textbox.Text = car.Name;
}
```