# ListView mouse hover with MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

What is the easiest way to get the item that the user has hovered on using the MVVM pattern?

I saw that there are quite a few events on the `ListView` concerning mouse input, but I couldn't find a bindable property.

Comment: want to get the item in c#? or just style it in the xaml code?

Comment: I need it in my viewmodel.

Comment: IMO, hovering is something you do with your mouse and screen because they are view related.  These things really shouldn't matter in your VM?

Comment: @NETscape they aren't view related if they have effect on your buisness logic.

Comment: If you didn't have a mouse or monitor, how do you hover over something?  Is this a hovercraft game?

Comment: So you are saying that hovering basically shouldn't have any effect on my application logic?

Comment: Anyways, you would set a data trigger on the item template, bound to a bool property in your item.  When the bool property setter is fired, you'd want to raise an event to its parent

Comment: I could give you an example if you use MVVM Light Framework!? In this case you can use EventToCommand to bind a command to your ViewModel on a MouseEnter event.

Comment: @SebastianRichter I would very much like to avoid MVVM Light because I don't want to add dependancies. There could be a more lightweigth solution.

Comment: @Chris ok then I'm sorry. But maybe this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450402/retrieve-cell-value-on-mouseenter-in-a-multiple-column-listview-with-data-bindin) will help you. The user asked a similiar question. Maybe you can bind to a property of our Viewmodel in die Code Behind in the event handler?!

Comment: I tried this for myself but i don't know if this violates MVVM pattern.

Comment: @SebastianRichter I've used this. The problem is that it doesn't allow two way binding.

Comment: @Chris Oh ok...Then I do not know further solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by doing a few things.You will encapsulate the listbox in its own UserControl. In the code behind in this user control you will need to declare a dependency property of type ICommand. In the xaml you will need to set up a ListBoxItem style that has the MouseEnterEvent handled.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter"
                         Handler="HandleEnter" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind you will to fire off the ICommand that you have as a DependecyProperty.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SendToViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SendToViewModel", typeof(ICommand), typeof(control), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private void HandleEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (SendToViewModel != null)
        {
            var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe != null)
            {
                if (SendToViewModel.CanExecute(fe.DataContext))
                {
                    SendToViewModel.Execute(fe.DataContext);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

So this will fire off the ICommand property that you should setup in your viewmodel passing in the datacontext of the ListBoxItem.